# Understanding strace of getpid() system call

Tags: c, operating-system, system-calls, ubuntu-18.04, strace

I recently started a class on Operating Systems and one of my assignments involves following the system call getpid() from the code that makes the call to the system library, through its implementation in the OS, back to the system library and the user program. I'm really lost and don't really know where to begin. I used strace, and I see getpid(), but I don't understand how to follow it.

I'm thinking I'm supposed to look at the system calls from getpid() to write. Can someone tell me if I'm on the right track and if not give some advice for understanding the output of strace?

**Output of strace**

[image]

Comment: Please don't post (links to) pictures of textual output — include the text in the question.

Comment: The `getpid()` system call is one of the simplest there is.  It is called; it returns a value; `strace` tells you what it returns — which is the PID of the process.  There isn't much more that can be said about it.  It pulls the data out of the process's control block.

Comment: I think s/he is asking you to find the code where the system call is implemented. And find how that code gets called. And find how *that* gets called. All the way back to the program. strace will not help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

> … one of my assignments involves following the system call getpid() from the code that makes the call to the system library, through its implementation in the OS, back to the system library and the user program. I'm really lost and don't really know where to begin.

Begin where the assignment begins: (1) *from the code that makes the call*. Then continue with (2) *the system library* function `getpid`, (3) *its implementation in the OS, back to the system library*, (4) and the user program.

> I used strace …

`strace` only shows you the how the OS is called and what it returns. For the assignment, you have to study the source codes or use debuggers, including a kernel debugger.